# Selenium put a script to sleep on unloading

Tags: python, selenium

I need help with my selenium script. Basically what my script does is that it searches for a LOGIN button and then click it. But when it clicks it and redirects you to another page (completelly different, not even same company, url etc.), the script turns off. When I then go my original page, the script stays turned off. I need to basically put it to sleep while on the another page, and then when re-entering the original page I need to wake the script up again. Please help me, thanks!

**Python:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.apage.cz/idk/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

try:
    search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mat-button-wrapper")
    if search.text == "LOGIN":
        search.click()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: For a standard re-direct, Selenium already waits for the page to load.  (It's a polling loop on the browser's readiness state... that includes a bunch of little sleeps in there.)

Comment: I know it waits for the page to load, though that is not what i was asking. I want it to basicly turn off And then on when the original one is loaded. Understandable?

Comment: seems like you'd either sleep while a certain condition is true, or just sleep until you get some input from the user of your script. (display a button or use console input)  The what or why isn't real clear... on/off terms are a little confusing, too... can you add some more details?

Comment: Yea sorry. Basically its what you described. The script would be put to sleep when the originál site is turned off by my script, And then when its reopened it would wake the script up. Or on user input as you stated. How is taht achieved?